# Multiple ResultSet to variable PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, database

On my database I have the table reserves, on the reserves I have inserted the following data:

[image]

Then I used the following query(this is just one part):

```
    $checkInresult = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT DAYOFMONTH(`checkIn`) FROM `reserves` WHERE `idApart` = 1 AND `expired` = 0"), 0,0);
    $checkOutresult = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT DAYOFMONTH(`checkOut`) FROM `reserves` WHERE `idApart` = 1 AND `expired` = 0"), 0,0);
    $curDay = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())"), 0,0);
    if((1 == $curDay) && (1 >= $checkInresult) && (1 <= $checkOutresult)){
        $day1 = "currentO";
    }elseif(1 == $curDay){
        $day1 = "currentA";
    }elseif((1 >= $checkInresult) && (1 <= $checkOutresult)){
        $day1 = "occupiedDay";
    }else{
        $day1 = "availableDay";
    }
```

And the html(only one part too):

```
<div id="calendar">
  <h1>June</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="<?php echo $day1; ?>"><center>1</center></td>
        <td class="<?php echo $day2; ?>"><center>2</center></td>
        <td class="<?php echo $day3; ?>"><center>3</center></td>
        <td class="<?php echo $day4; ?>"><center>4</center></td>
        <td class="<?php echo $day5; ?>"><center>5</center></td>
        <td class="<?php echo $day6; ?>"><center>6</center></td>
        <td class="<?php echo $day7; ?>"><center>7</center></td>
    </tr>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

And I want the 2nd data to apear marked with red too without making too many ifs like same variable contains the checkIn and checkOut data from both datas. Is it possible? Or is it too confusing? :s

Comment: You are only using the first row with mysql_result. Try while($row=mysql_fetch_array()){...}

Comment: @colburton but it works on the "if's" that I have? and how does that while works? sorry I'm new at php/sql :/

Comment: Do you mean something like `"SELECT DAYOFMONTH(`checkIn`), DAYOFMONTH(`checkOut`) FROM `reserves...`? And: `$checkResults = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(...`?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles no, I have 2 datas on the result set, the query I am doing only show me the first one, I want to get both in the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
$curDay = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())"), 0, 0);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DAYOFMONTH(`checkIn`) AS checkIn, DAYOFMONTH(`checkOut`) AS checkout FROM `reserves` WHERE `idApart` = 1 AND `expired` = 0");

// initialize all days as available
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    $days[$i] = 'availableDay';
}

// mark the current day
$days[$curDay] = 'currentA';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $checkInresult = $row['checkin'];
    $checkOutresult = $row['checkout'];

    // run through occupied days
    for ($i = $checkInresult; $i <= $checkOutresult; $i++) {
        if ($i == $curDay) {
            // we hit the current day again, so mark as occupied
            $days[$i] = 'currentO';
        } else {
            // occupy any other day
            $days[$i] = 'occupiedDay';
        }
    }
}
```

For output use:

```
<td class="<?php echo $days[1]; ?>"><center>1</center></td>
```

Comment: this is the full code I have http://jsfiddle.net/psyko/8LVub/ I tryed the way you said but I got some erros :/

Answer (score 1):

And loop over days to make table:

```
<tr>

<?php

for ( $day = 1; $day <= $days; $day++ ) {
    if ( $weekend ) { echo '</tr><tr>'; }
    echo '<td class="' . ${'day' .$day} . '"><center>' . $day . '</center></td>';
}

?>

</tr>
```

Still need to figure out what `$weekend` is for the particular month.

Comment: man awesome, its works without that many ifs :p but now only shows the 2nd data xD

Comment: I did it with the @colburton version but I used your way to make the table, didnt knew that, thank you :)